# Moving a buffer in vim across instances of vim

Tags: unix, vim

Is this possible to do?

Conceptually, a solution should apply across a lot of possible configurations, ranging from two vim instances running in separate virtual terminals in panes in a tmux window, to being in separate terminals on separate machines in separate geographical regions, one or both connected over network (in other words, the vims are hosted by two separate shell processes, which they would already be under tmux anyhow).

The case that prompted me to ponder this:

**I have two tmux panels both with vim open and I want to use the Vim yank/paste to copy across the files.**

But it only works if I've got them both running in the same instance of Vim, so I am forced to either:

1. use tmux's copy/paste feature to get the content over (which is somewhat tedious and finicky), or
2. use the terminal (PuTTY, iTerm2)'s copy/paste feature to get the content over (which is similarly tedious but not subject to network latency, however this only works up to a certain size of text payload to copy at which point this method will not work at all due to the terminal not knowing the contents of the not-currently-visible parts of the file), or
3. lose Vim buffer history/context and possibly shell history/context in reopening the file manually in one of the Vim instances in either a split buffer or tab and then closing the other terminal context (much less tedious than 1 for large payloads but more so with small payloads).

This is a bit of a PITA and could all be avoided if I have the foresight of switching to an appropriate terminal already running vim to open my files but the destiny of workflow and habit rarely match up with that which would have been convenient.

So the question is, does there exist a command or the possibility of a straighforwardly-constructed (shell) script that allows me to join buffers across independently running vim instances? Am having a hard time getting Google to answer that adequately.

In the absence of an adequate answer (or if it is determined with reasonable certainty that Vim does not possess the features to accomplish the transfer of buffers across its instances), a good implementation (bindable to keys) for approach 3 above is acceptable.

Meanwhile I'll go back to customizing my vim config further and forcing myself to use as few instances of vim as possible.

Comment: write buffer to file, insert from file?

Comment: it is possible to make vim use the OS clipboard but I never succeeded.

Comment: drops vim search history, vim undo history, vim command history and so on (though it is beginning to look like that is unavoidable)

Comment: it may also be possible to bind a key to a function which in the background emulates buffers over some files in, for example `/tmp` without changing anything else.

Comment: @perreal is it possible to put vim into a mode which monitors for updates to a file? In which case I could set up a shared temp file that can be auto-synced.

Comment: I just use the native os GUI be it X or aqua or whatever  to cut paste text selected from the terminal window with a mouse.   Not sure how you could expect vim to do this between sessions.   Especially if they are on different systems

Comment: @StevenLu, have you seen this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_and_paste_between_Vim_instances

Comment: @perreal thanks for link. Also found `set autoread` which answers my question i posed

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, does `"*` or `"+` register help? you could copy/yank text from one vim to that register, than in another vim do `"+p` for example.

Comment: @Kent could you give me a little more about where to find documentation for those registers? Hard to google, these things.

Comment: @StevenLu  you could in vim `:h registers` then `/Selection and drop`

Comment: @Kent From what I am getting out of the vim help there is those registers are for working with X (window manager)? I need them working across terminal vim sessions

Comment: you meant `terminal == tty`?

Comment: @Kent without being overly pedantic I hazard a guess of "yes", `tty`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, Vim can't share a session between multiple instances. This is how it's designed and it doesn't provide any session-sharing facility. Registers, on-the-fly mappings/settings, command history, etc. are local to a Vim session and you can't realistically do anything about that.

---

But your title is a bit misleading: you wrote "buffer" but it looks like you are only after copying/pasting (which involves "register", not "buffers") from one Vim instance to another. Is that right? If so, why don't you simply get yourself a proper build with clipboard support?

Copying/yanking across instances is as easy as `"+y` in one and `"+p` in another.

Obviously, this won't work if your Vim instances are on different systems. In such a situation, `"+y` in the source Vim and system-provided paste in the destination Vim (possibly with `:set paste`) is the most common solution.

---

If you are on a Mac, install MacVim and move the accompanying `mvim` shell script somewhere in your path. You can use the MacVim executable *in* your terminal with `mvim -v`.

If you are on Linux, install the vim-gnome package from your package manager.

If you are on Windows, install the latest "Vim without Cream".

---

But the whole thing looks like an XY problem to me. Using Vim's built-in `:e[dit]` command efficiently is probably the best solution to what appears to be your underlying problem: editing many files from many different shells.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the buffer, but you can quickly close and reopen the file from one vim instance to another. If your buffer is saved, this is essentially like "moving a buffer".

First of all, make sure your unnamed register is shared with your system-wide clipboard by having this in your `.vimrc`:

```rc
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

Then copy the full path of the opened file on the old buffer using:

```
:let @+ = expand("%:p")
```

I'd make a binding for that, which optionally could include prior saving and closing of the buffer, so that the swp won't cause any issues when you try to open the same file in your new buffer.

With the full path of your file in your clipboard, you can move to a new vim instance and run:

```
:e <C-r>+
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In honor of this post’s 10th anniversary, I’ll post my update in an answer.

These days I don’t really have the problem that was described in the question because a functional method to reliably bring buffer contents out into the host terminal’s clipboard is possible with OSC52 based vim/nvim plugins. The one I use is `ojroques/nvim-osc52`.

I then use some binds like these

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>y", safeRequire("osc52").copy_operator, { expr = true, desc = "Copy to host term system clipboard via OSC 52" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>yy", "<leader>y_", { remap = true, desc = "Copy entire line to host term system clipboard via OSC 52" })
vim.keymap.set("x", "<leader>y", safeRequire("osc52").copy_visual, { desc = "Copy visual selection to host term system clipboard via OSC 52" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>Y", "ggVG<leader>y", { remap = true, desc = "Copy entire buffer to host clipboard via OSC 52"})
```

to quickly and easily exfiltrate any file buffer into the system clipboard. This even works on iOS since most any terminal emulator implements OSC52 clipboard.

Pasting is always easy, it’s the yanking/copying that was an issue until recently.